# How does a servlet get data from another servlet?

Tags: java, servlets, response

My problem like this:
I have two servlets: 
servlet_A: `http://localhost:8080/test/servlet_wait_for_response`
servlet_B: `http://localhost:8080/test/servlet_send_data?data=xxx`
1. I use Firefox invoking servlet_A, and the servlet_A does nothing but wait;
2. I use Chrome invoking servlet_B, and send "helloworld" to the server, for example: `http://localhost:8080/test/servlet_send_data?data=helloworld`
3. servlet_B get the message "helloworld", then send this message to servlet_A;
4. servlet_A get the message "helloworld" from servlet_B, then response this message to Firefox.

Comment: You should try messaging service. The requirement what you want could be done by JMS. If what you want is duplex communication, try WebSockets.

Comment: Boss doesn't allow me to use JMS. Finally, I sleep servlet_A, then put 'helloword' into application, then notify servlet_A.

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer like below:

```
static String msg = null;

@RequestMapping(value = "/wait_for_data", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public String waitData() throws InterruptedException{
    while(msg==null){
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
    }
    return msg;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/send_data", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public String sendData(String data){
    msg = data;
    return "OK";
}
```